# How do I disable filebeat's close_inactive setting?

Tags: filebeat

My filebeat (container from `docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.1.2`) harvesters are being closed by the close_inactive and I don't want them to be. The documentation from `close_inactive` from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#close-inactive) states

> When this option is enabled, Filebeat closes the file handle if a file has not been harvested for the specified duration.
>
> ...
>
> You can use time strings like 2h (2 hours) and 5m (5 minutes). The default is 5m.

My file handles are being closed after 5 minutes. I know I can increase the close_inactive time, but the first sentence indicates that the option can be disabled altogether.

I've tried things like `close_inactive: false` but no luck. How do I disable the close_inactive setting?

Comment: sounds weird, are you using the last version?

Comment: I've added the version to the question. We're using a container from elastic: `docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.1.2`

Answer (score 2):

If you add the option `close_inactive: -1` in your filebeat.yml, Filebeat will never close the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use yaml anchors here to ignore code duplication.

For example:

```
.global: &global
      ignore_older: 30m
      scan_frequency: 5m
      harvester_limit: 1
      close_inactive: 1m
      clean_inactive: 45m
      close_removed: true
      clean_removed: true

filebeat:
  inputs:
    - type: log
      paths:
        - "/var/log/messages*"
      exclude_files:
        - ".gz$"
      <<: *global
    - type: log
      paths:
        - "/var/log/nginx/access.log*"
      exclude_files:
        - ".gz$"
      <<: *global
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `close_inactive: 0`?  That is what close_timeout is set to by default, which disables it.

Comment: Just tried it, and it looks like it sets it to zero seconds and closes files immediately. I see this in the log: `2018/08/07 18:09:09.510266 harvester.go:240: INFO File is inactive: /var/log/myfilebeat.log . Closing because close_inactive of 0s reached.`

Comment: Sorry about that.  I would be nice if this was consistent with close_timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. It would be nice if it was consistent with its own documentation too.