# Maximum close_inactive time for filebeat harvesters

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

I was wondering what was the longest time possible to set in that `close_inactive` field, because I want it to be the longest as possible ([since we cannot set it as infinite by any means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684423/how-do-i-disable-filebeats-close-inactive-setting)). Their documentation does not precise it, they just put [examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.3/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-close-inactive) like `2h` and `5m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit to the `close_inactive` time.
You can see it in [FileBeat git](https://github.com/elastic/beats/tree/master/filebeat) 
In addition, if you like,You can search the variable `CloseInactive` in this [repository](https://github.com/elastic/beats/search?q=CloseInactive&unscoped_q=CloseInactive) and see it for your self.